# Issue in drupal the directory sites/default/files is not writable

Tags: drupal, installation

To solve these issues display in process of installing Drupal as:

- Go to your "drupal" folder and make permission 777
- Then open "sites" folder and make it 777
- Choose "default" folder and make it 777
- Open "files" and choose "setting.php" to change permission to 777

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an answer without a question. Self-answered material **still needs an on-topic question**.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving public right to execute read and write files in your directories. Clearly not a good idea.
Check this link for more infos on what to do in production environnement (it also explains basic chmod values wich you seem to not be understanding) : https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 0):

Some normal permissions would be `0644` for files and `0755` for directories. Then i.e. settings.php since there is no need for it to be writable you should fully forbid writing.

If only `0777` "solves" your issue, maybe problem are not permission values but file owner. It happens that you upload files with one (FTP) account Apache is running website with some other, which is not allowed to write over first one. So changing file owner could solve the issue.